# Getting tweets having images/video/article link

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

Using twitter API we can get tweets.

Is there any way to get only those tweets  having either image/video/article link in it?

Or how to curate such tweets?

as per this https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets we can get only tweets. Could not give any option for tweets having I/V or article

Comment: Did you search in the API yourself? Did you try processing the tweets yourself?

Comment: Yes, already checked https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets api page, but did not get any clue

Comment: I'm not sure Twitter has such a call in the API. But you can get all the tweets and filter for the links yourself.

Comment: @VincentBeltman: filtering not sure how better will work, sometimes tweets shows image though it is not in tweet.

Answer (score 2):

If you include the `filter:images` or `filter:videos` or `filter:links` values inside your Search expression, you can narrow the search to include just the kinds of Tweets you want.